# Automatically running a command when android device connected usb

Tags: android, usb, autorun

I'm developing an app on the device. running `adb reverse ...` every time, is frustrating. is there a way to run a custom command or auto bind the ports, every time a USB android is connected?

I appreciate answers for Windows/Linux/Mac.

Comment: if you are using linux use this https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28548/how-to-run-custom-scripts-upon-usb-device-plug-in

Comment: what's your os?

Comment: @kamyarhaqqani I'm currently on Windows but I want answer for each OS.

Comment: @rajkavadia I assume this will apply to Mac too. but it is a little general, and runs on every usb device connection. since what I want to run is a safe command, this will work for me. thank you. I'll check that out.

Comment: If you want to run the debug command every time than check for port 5555 ,if its open in usb then connect.I think it will be a little tricky but it will work.@AliKazemkhanloo

Answer (score 1):

You could use autoadb to automate on device plugin. Here is the link to repository

https://github.com/rom1v/autoadb

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. This is a welcomed as a Comment, but does not meet SO standards for Answers.

Comment: I was trying to comment but my reputation didn't let me do it

Comment: This worked perfectly for my use case. had to cross-compile it for windows though.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this annoyance as well. I made this shell script to automatically run adb reverse whenever my phone is plugged in. Hope it helps. I think it can also be adapted to run on Windows.

```
#!/bin/sh
while :
do
    echo Waiting for Android USB device
    adb wait-for-usb-device reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
    echo Connection established
    adb wait-for-usb-disconnect
    echo Disconnected
done
```